# JDK17:UseConcMarkSweepGC flag issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-17

I have jdk 17 configured and am trying to run

```
sbt clean compile
```

It gives error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

But in ....\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions, I dont see this  flag.

So where is this flag actually configured?

Comment: Aside - It was [removed in JDK-14](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/363), mostly the warning has been transformed into an error.
Just ensure you are using a framework(sbt) which is up to date with the JDK version you are using.